# SwiftUI - How to programatically load a new view from the current view (Xcode 15 beta 6)

Tags: swiftui, view, navigationview, tabview

The approaches that I used in earlier versions have stopped working, in fact they crash. The culprit is, I believe, TabView.

To load a new View as follows still works:

```
 NavigationLink(destination: NextView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true))   {
                        Text("Press to see the next view")
                    }
```

And if I want to load a TabView this will, initially, also still work (MenuView generates the TabView):

```
 NavigationLink(destination: MenuView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true))   {
                        Text("Press to Continue")
                           
 }
```

And the chosen View with the TabView at the bottom of the screen appears:

[image]

But from the next view how to I, programatically, go to another View? I used to be able to call:

```
HStack{
     Button(action: {selectedTab = TabChoice.calculate}, label: { Text("Press to go to next view")
     }
}
```

This no longer works and crashes to @main with no errors in the debug screen.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        LaunchScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your NavigationStack is for each tab and not 1 above the tab view. But without an MRE we can’t help. That is what was wrong with the previous question where you posted a ton of code. We need a crashing Minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Understood and appreciated. Most examples* of TabView, from the TabView onwards, don't use the NavigationStack. I use it initially to load the MenuView which initiates the Tabs. After that I had removed it and it "did" previously work. * Paul Hudson/Hacking with Swift

Comment: The NavigationView must be inside the TabView. That isn’t optional per HIG it is very often done the opposite.

Comment: I'm just about to load the MRE version and will delete this question shortly afterwards. Many thanks for your viewing and help.